# How do I give file path for code to be checked in at TFS?

Tags: unit-testing, tfs

I am writing a test code (I'm just a beginner) where I need to give a file name located in my local box. I need to check-in this code as well as the file in TFS, so that when other people take latest version, they get both.

```
//At my local box
string myFilePath= "D:\BACKUP\samplefile.extension";
```

For TFS check-in, I gave following path but it failed

```
string myFilePath= "$MyProjectServer\SomeFolder\samplefile.extension";
```

Now my question is:

- How can I specify the file path in my Code, so that after check-in when other people in my team take the latest version, the code will point to right file location in TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can proceed:

1. Add a file to the root of your unit test project and set `Copy to Output Directory: Copy always`. For example add `test.txt`. Because the file is part of the project structure it will be added under source control as all the other files.
2. Use the [`[DeploymentItem]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) attribute in your unit test to indicate which file will be used. You also have the possibility to organize the test files into sub-folders.

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   [DeploymentItem("test.txt")]
   public void Index()
   {
       // use relative path to read the file
       var actual = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
       Assert.AreEqual(actual, "some content");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your TFS path `string myFilePath= "$MyProjectServer\SomeFolder\samplefile.extension"` is in the wrong format.

The correct format for an itemspec is:

```
string myFilePath= "$/MyProjectServer/SomeFolder/samplefile.extension";
```

Note the addition of the slash after the `$` and the change of backslashes to forward slashes throughout.

Comment: When i gave this path, it gives me file not found exception. Do i need to check-in the file first to give the path?

Comment: I get this error. $/MyProjectServer/SomeFolder/samplefile.extension
The file name or path is not valid or it cannot be accessed

Comment: I used Relative Path instead and now it is Working Fine. Thanks for replying.